# 2012 Macbook Air - Lion will not reinstall

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup

I have a 2012 Macbook Air, and its local recovery drive has been wiped. I used the internet recovery mode (Command + R) but for some reason when I try to reinstall Mac OSX Lion, I get a message that says "can't download additional components." I have research online but solutions such as changing the time does not solve this problem. So my second attempt was creating a high sierra bootable USB and installing that to the Macbook Air. The Macbook will attempt to boot to it however, about half way loading the progress bar, a circle with a line across appears.

Comment: Do you have another computer to check and see if the High Sierra USB stick will boot on? The first thing to do is eliminate the USB drive as a suspect.

Comment: Hello @Calion yes I have tried the bootable High Sierra USB on a 2014 Macbook Air, and it works just fine! I was able to boot into the disk utility as well.

Comment: Okay, so here is the solution I found after troubleshooting. This "can't download additional components" issue is beyond what someone even with IT skills can just fix at home. I ended up going to the Apple Store and they reimaged the Macbook Air from their local server on site. Unfortunate solution since Apple Stores are not always physically available. After speaking with the Genius Bar technician, they said that because the 2012 Macbook Air are no longer supported by Apple, the Internet Recovery certificate has expired. Not even a time change locally on the device can fix this.

Comment: I feared it was something like that.